# Flex/Bison: yytext skips over a value

Tags: c, linux, bison, flex-lexer

I've been racking my brain for two days trying to figure out why the program is behaving this way. For a class project, I'm trying to write a program that parses an address and outputs it a certain way. Before I actually get to the output portion of the program, I just wanted to make sure my Bison-fu was actually correct and outputting some debugging information correctly.

It looks as if Flex and Bison are cooperating with each other nicely, as expected, but for some reason, when I get to the parsing of the third line of the address, yytext just skips over the zip code and goes straight to the new line.

Below is a stripped down version of my Flex and Bison files that I tested and still outputs the same thing as the full version:

```
[19:45]<Program4> $ cat scan.l
%option noyywrap
%option nounput
%option noinput

%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
#include "program4.h"
%}

%%

[\ \t]+                 { /* Eat whitespace */}
[\n]                    { return EOLTOKEN; }
","                     { return COMMATOKEN; }
[0-9]+                  { return INTTOKEN; }
[A-Za-z]+               { return NAMETOKEN; }
[A-Za-z0-9]+            { return IDENTIFIERTOKEN; }

%%

/*This area just occupies space*/
[19:45]<Program4> $ cat parse.y


%{
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "program4.h"

%}

%union {int num; char id[20]; }
%start locationPart
%expect 0
%token <num> NAMETOKEN
%token <num> EOLTOKEN
%token <num> INTTOKEN
%token <num> COMMATOKEN
%type <id> townName zipCode stateCode

%%

/* Entire block */
locationPart:           townName COMMATOKEN stateCode zipCode EOLTOKEN          
{ printf("Rule 12: LP: TN COMMA SC ZC EOL: %s\n", yytext); }
| /* bad location part */                               
{ printf("Rule 13: LP: Bad location part: %s\n", yytext); }
                    ;

/* Lil tokens */
townName:               NAMETOKEN                                               
{ printf("Rule 23: TN: NAMETOKEN: %s\n", yytext); }
                    ;

stateCode:              NAMETOKEN                                               
{ printf("Rule 24: SC: NAMETOKEN: %s\n", yytext); }
                    ;

zipCode:                INTTOKEN DASHTOKEN INTTOKEN                             
{ printf("Rule 25: ZC: INT DASH INT: %s\n", yytext); }
                    | INTTOKEN                                              
{ printf("Rule 26: ZC: INT: %s\n", yytext); }
                    ;

%% 

int yyerror (char const *s){
  extern int yylineno; //Defined in lex

  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: %s at symbol \"%s\"\n at line %d.\n", s, yytext, 
yylineno);
  exit(1);
}
[19:45]<Program4> $ cat addresses/zip.txt
Rockford, HI 12345
[19:45]<Program4> $ parser < addresses/zip.txt
Operating in parse mode.

Rule 23: TN: NAMETOKEN: Rockford
Rule 24: SC: NAMETOKEN: HI
Rule 26: ZC: INT:

Rule 12: LP: TN COMMA SC ZC EOL:

Parse successful!
[19:46]<Program4> $
```

As you can see near the bottom, it prints `Rule 26: ZC: INT:` but fails to print the 5 digit zip code. It's like the program just skips the number and stores the newline instead. Any ideas why it won't store and print the zip code?

Notes:

- yytext is defined as an extern in my .h file (not posted here);
- I am using the `-vdy` flags to compile the parse.c file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `yytext` is a global variable, it's overwritten and you will have to copy it in your *lex* script. In a pure parser, even though it's not global anymore it's still reused and passed as a parameter so it's incorrect to use it's value like you are attempting.

Also, don't use it in bison, instead use `$n` where `n` is the position of the token in the rule. You probably need the `%union` directive changed to something like

```
%union {
    int number;
    char *name;
};
```

So in the *flex* file, if you want to capture the text do something like

```
[A-Za-z]+               { yylval.name = strdup(yytext); return NAMETOKEN; }
```

and remember, do not use `yytext` in *bison*, it's an internal thing used by the lexer.

Then and since you have defined a type for the zip code

```
/* Entire block */
locationPart:           townName COMMATOKEN stateCode zipCode EOLTOKEN {
    printf("Rule 12: LP: TN COMMA SC ZC EOL: town:%s, stateCode:%d zip-code:%s\n", $1, $3, $4); 
}
```

Comment: The problem with this mechanism is that the parser needs to know when it must free() the yylval, or you leak memory. That's quite a price to pay, especially since yytext is intended to be used as a global variable (that's why it's not declared static, and why you have a mechanism to change its name).

Comment: @Jabberwock, in a complete and real parser you would normally pass a pointer to an object that contains the means to create an AST and then you can free everything you need when you need to. Of course, there are other methods, that would not require copying, for example if you know it's fixed length, then you can use an array combined with `strcpy()`.

Comment: Using bison to create an AST seems wrong to me--yes, an AST is far more flexible than a bison parser, but for simple parsing needs bison is perfect.  And I don't understand your point about "other methods that don't require copying...use an array combined with strcpy."  Calling strcpy() does a data copy.  (And all of this is orthogonal to my original point that yytext is intended as a global variable--it is part of flex's API.  There is no reason to add complexity and risk memory leaks to avoid using it.)

Comment: @Jabberwock You are right, I didn't mean "*copying*" I meant dynamic memory allocation. And I mean, that you can build an AST from a bison parser, and indeed you can. I don't understand what you mean by "*an AST is far more flexible than a bison parser*", they are not comparable. I was just trying to mention an example where a context, with all the strings captured and organized in such a way that they can be used at the end of the parsing, and freed later is possible if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to trace the workings of your parser, you are much better off enabling bison's trace feature. It's really easy. Just add the `-t` or `--debug` flag to the `bison` command to generate the code, and then add a line to actually produce the tracing:

```
/* This assumes you have #included the parse.tab.h header */
int main(void) {
#if YYDEBUG
   yydebug = 1;
#endif
```

This is explained in [the Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracing); the `#if` lets your program compile if you leave off the `-t` flag. While on the subject of flags, I strongly suggest you do not use the `-y` flag; it is for compiling old Yacc programs which relied on certain obsolete features. If you don't use `-y`, then bison will use the basename of your `.y` file with extensions `.tab.c` and `.tab.h` for the generated files.

Now, your bison file says that some of your tokens have semantic types, but your flex actions do not set semantic values for these tokens and your bison actions don't use the semantic values. Instead, you simply print the value of `yytext`. If you think about this a bit, you should be able to see why it won't work. Bison is a *lookahead* parser; it makes its parsing decisions based on the the current parsing state and a peek at the next token (if necessary). It peeks at the next token by calling the lexer. And when you call the lexer, it changes the value of `yytext`.

Bison (unlike other yacc implementations) doesn't always peek at the next token. But in your zipcode rule, it has no alternative, since it cannot tell whether the next token is a `-` or not without looking at it. In this case, it is not a dash; it is a newline. So guess what `yytext` contains when you print it out in the zipcode action.

If your tokenizer were to save the text in the `id` semantic value member  (which is what it is for) then your parser would be able to access the semantic values as `$1`, `$2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
zipCode:              INTTOKEN DASHTOKEN INTTOKEN     { // case 25 }        
                    | INTTOKEN                        { // case 26 }  
                    ;
```

The parser doesn't know which rule to take--25 or 26--until it's parsed the next token to see if it is a DASHTOKEN.  By the time the code is executed, yytext has already been overwritten.

The easiest way to handle this is to have a production that takes the INTTOKENs and returns what was in yytext[] in malloc()'d memory.  Something like:

```
zipCode:              inttoken DASHTOKEN inttoken
                         {
                              printf("Rule 25: zip is %s-%s\n", $1, $3);
                              free($1);
                              free($3);
                         }                    
                    | inttoken
                         {
                              printf("Rule 26: zip is %s\n", $1);
                              free($1);
                         }                    
                    ;

inttoken: INTTOKEN { $$ = strdup(yytext); }
        ;
```